# add a "pre_value" to set /p userinp=

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have following code, asking for user to fill in filename:

```
echo Type in your filename (path + filename):
set userinp=
set /p userinp= ^>
```

What I would like:
already 'prefill' fullpath+filename, which the user can then edit.
In most cases, this would be: %cd%+filename (most common file selected)

```
Type in your filename (path + filename):
> D:\Download\MyFile.txt
```

(the string 'D:\Download\MyFile.txt' should be editable)

NB: must be achieved strictly with Windows batch commands; no use of the other languages and/or programs.

Comment: And why `set /p userip=^>%cd%\file.txt` cannot be used?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: So you want a command that "types" into the `set /P` prompt without pressing _Enter_? There is no change with pure [tag:cmd] commands...

Comment: @aschipfl: This question is purely philosophic: Is `cscript` a "pure cmd command" or not?  **`;)`**

Comment: #npocmaka: you should try what you've proposed; then you understand what I meant (had same problem). @Aacini: humm, philosophic. I suppose that is actually a complement... Anyways: I like your answer best; short and "understandable". Had to do some reseach  on why this works, but quick search here give me that answer. thx. #Squashman: you came up with a solution that is 'exactly/literally' what I asked for (but also far more complex). I will go for #Aacini's solution because of simplicity. To justify: yes, strictly DOS like in: 'no add. java/JS/etc scripts' nor external keyb util, Cygwin, etc

Comment: I cannot answer that, @Aacini... ;-) anyway, my (mis-)interpretation was that `cscript` is forbidden, even for hybrid scripts, because of the statement "no use of the other languages and/or programs"...

Comment: @Badt_Paul, you still seem to be contradicting yourself.  You said **no add. java/JS/etc scripts** but that is exactly what Antonio's script is doing. `cscript //nologo //E:JScript`.  No offense Antonio.  Just trying to make a point.  If you are going to accept Antonio's answer then select it as the answer.

Comment: No problem @Squashman; however, as a reply, I would like to note that your solution does not "add a pre_value **to set /p**", but replace it instead! Your edition method just allows to delete the last character via BackSpace key, but all other `set /p` edition keys don't works. Although it would be possible to do a more extensive edition with additional code, there is no way to read arrow keys in a Batch file (unless PowerShell is used). It seems that the answer to this question is: there is no way to do that using "pure cmd commands".

Comment: @aschipfl: I invite you and anybody interested to join this philosophic discussion. **`:-)`** Should `choice` be considered a "pure Batch command" in Windows XP? Remember that Win XP did not included choice.exe file, but you may get it via a supplemental install (the same point apply to robocopy in certain Windows versions). If your answer is "yes", I invite you to explain why. What about a choice.exe file _written by myself_ that mimics MS choice in every detail? Should it be considered "pure Batch command" in Windows XP or in any previous version?

Comment: @Aacini, this is a difficult topic ;-): Actually I prefer the term "native `cmd` command"; I would say, all commands that appear when typing `help` in the console are "native" (both internal (like `cd`) and external (like `xcopy`) ones); all those are (somehow) guaranteed to be included in the Windows distribution; there are a lot more command line tools (like `timeout`, `ipconfig`, `certutil`, etc.), which I would *not* consider as "native", because they *might* be missing in some Windows distributions (Basic or Home editions, some OEM versions);...

Comment: @Aacini, ...hence both `choice` and `robocopy` are "native" since Vista but *not* for XP; therefore, I would *not* consider any custom-made command line tools as "native".

Comment: @Squashman: if I would have asked an 'open' question, many would have posted solutions using powershell, vbs, cygwin, etc. In essence, I wanted a solution that would have NO need to depend on any external source (incl any type of external code, whether generated from within the batchfile, or not) but only uses "basic" DOS. And indeed, csript command is part of that DOS set (just like Choice) ~ btw: already implemented, and working as expected.

Comment: @Badt_Paul, stop referring to cmd.exe as DOS. It's not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is simple and have the advantage that you may use the standard command-line navigation keys, that is, besides the edition you may enter the first letters of a folder/file and browse through the existent folders/files with TAB key. You may even put `"{TAB}"` in the prefill value to automatically prefill with the first file in current directory, or `"Dat{TAB}"` for the first file that start with "Dat", etc.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
echo Type in your filename (path + filename):
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%cd%\commonFile.ext"
set "userinp="
set /P "userinp=>"
echo Value read: "%userinp%"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Note that the `cscript` command, used here to execute a line of JScript code, is a standard "DOS" command provided with all Windows versions since XP on.

**EDIT**: *Include the path of first file*

You may put `"%cd%\{TAB}"` in the prefill value in order to get the first file in current folder *including the path*; however, this method fail if the path contain any space. The new code below fix this point, although it still may fail if at any point in the path exist two folders with same name until the first space and the wanted folder is not the first one.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "curdir="
for %%a in ("%cd:\=" "%") do (
   for /F "tokens=1*" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "curdir=!curdir!\%%b"
      if "%%c" neq "" set "curdir=!curdir!{TAB}"
   )
)
echo Type in your filename (path + filename):
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%curdir:~1%\{TAB}"
set "userinp="
set /P "userinp=>"
echo Value read: "%userinp%"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Getting some strange output with the second set of code. I have not tested the first one. I currently have the batch file running from my desktop. On my desktop, I have a shortcut named `15JFWtime .xlsx - Shortcut.lnk`. When I run the code, this is what appears after my set /p prompt: `"C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop\~$15JFWtime .xlsx"`

Comment: @aacini: I understood that Sendkeys is no longer 'supported' - blocked - on Windows 10; Is this correct? and what would be a good "replacement/correction"? (without disabling UAC, as this seems to be a "solution" for some)

Answer (score 0):

[Code taken from aGerman on Dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4962#p28989)

```
@echo off &setlocal

call :PredefInput "Type in your filename (path + filename):>" "D:\Download\MyFile.txt" filename

echo Your filename is %filename%
pause

goto :eof
:::::::::: END ::::::::::


:PredefInput  ByVal_Message  ByVal_Predefined  ByRef_VarName
if "%__PRIN__%" neq "__PRIN__" (
  setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
  if "%~3"=="" endlocal &exit /b 0
  set "M=%~1" &set "S=%~2" &set "N=0" &set "__PRIN__=__PRIN__"
  for /f %%i in ('"prompt;$h&for %%i in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%i"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  <nul set /p "=.!BS! !BS!!M!!S!"
  set "S=A!S!"
  for /l %%i in (12,-1,0) do (
    set /a "N|=1<<%%i"
    for %%j in (!N!) do if "!S:~%%j,1!"=="" set /a "N&=~1<<%%i"
  )
  for %%i in (!N!) do endlocal &set "N=%%i"
)
set "C="
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('2^>nul xcopy /lw "%~f0" "%~f0"') do if not defined C set "C=%%i"
set "C=%C:~-1%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not defined C (
  echo(
  if defined S (
    for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &endlocal &set "%~3=%%i" &exit /b %N%
  ) else endlocal &endlocal &set "%~3=" &exit /b 0
)
if "!BS!"=="!C!" (
  set "C="
  if defined S set /a "N -= 1" &set "S=!S:~,-1!" &<nul set /p "=%BS% %BS%"
) else set /a "N += 1" &<nul set /p "=.%BS%!C!"
if not defined S (
  endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%C%"
) else for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("!S!") do endlocal &set "N=%N%" &set "S=%%i%C%"
goto PredefInput
```