# default value of Set /p in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, set, default

Is there a way to present a default value in a `set /p` statement in a Windows batch script?

For example, something like this:

```
set /p MyVar=My Default Value
echo $MyVar$
```

If the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without typing anything else, then `MyVar gets that default value.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered several times before, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549048/is-there-anyway-to-have-preset-data-for-user-input-in-a-batch-file/23551029#23551029), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857183/how-can-i-run-cmd-from-batch-file-and-add-text-to-line-without-executing/29887523#29887523), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595252/add-a-pre-value-to-set-p-userinp/40597703#40597703), ...

Comment: @Aacini Yeah might be... Interestingly I literally _always_ find those duplicates in top positions of any search result. :) But thanks to your 1st link I found what I was really looking for, i.e. not just setting a default value but also preseting that default value to the user.

Answer (score 26):

This:

```
SET /P "MyVar=" || SET "MyVar=My Default Value"
```

([Read more](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)).

---

You could also use this:

```
SET /P "MyVar="
IF NOT DEFINED MyVar SET "MyVar=My Default Value"
```

Comment: You could also preset the value because `set` won't overwrite it if the user presses enter without typing, e.g. `set "MyVar=Default Value" & set /p "MyVar=Enter value: "`.

Comment: @eryksun If the user presses enter without typing `SET "MyVar=My Default Value"` is processed (tested on Windows 10).

Comment: @eryksun It's late... fixed it, thanks. How does it come it's more reliable, tho?

Comment: It's a potential parsing problem with mismatched quoting if the user enters a string with double quotes.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one method.

It will set `%1` as `myvar` if defined, then skip the prompt and echo `myvar` else it will store `Default Value` as the default, but if someone types in another value, it will overwrite the default. Not you can also use `%2` `%3` etc.

```
@echo off
set "myvar=%1"
if "%myvar%"=="" set /p "myvar=Enter Value: " || set "myvar=Default Value"
echo %myvar%
```

to see results, save the batch and run the following from `cmdline`:

```
batchfile.cmd Default
```

Which will skip prompt and just echo:

> Default

```
batchfile.cmd
```

Which will prompt `Enter Value:` just hit enter, which will then echo:

> Default Value

Lastly

```
batchfile.cmd
```

and enter a value, which wil lecho the entered value.

Answer (score 5):

The solutions proposed above did not work for me or they worked in a very clunky way.

This is (an obvious) simple solution to the problem I applied:

```
SET Docdir=D:\Documents\
SET /p Docdir="Target directory (Press Enter to keep <%Docdir%>): "
```

It results in the following prompt:

```
Target directory (Press Enter to use <D:\Documents\>):
```

User then see what's the default value and can accept it with `Enter` key